# Something goes wrong with my controller I may have mistake somewhere of it

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my controller

```
function new_post(){
    if($_POST){
        $data=array(
            'title'=>$_POST['title'],
            'post'=>$_POST['post'],
            'active'=>1);
    $this->post->insert_post($data);
    redirect('post/');
    } 
    else {
        $this->load->view('new_post');
    }
}
```

This is not working is this controller fine,
**model**
this is the model only it inserts to the form.

```
  function insert_post($data){
        $this->db->insert('posts',$data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
```

If I change this to

```
                  $data=array(
                'title'=>$_POST['title'],
                'post'=>$_POST['post'],
                'active'=>1);
              $this->post->insert_post($data);
```

Then it works

Have I did any mistake on first controller because it's not inserting....

Regards

Comment: How to call `new_post()` ?

Comment: what is the error? show us output

Comment: @rcpyan the problem is on the controller ..............just not inserting and to shows me (else) redirection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the condition to this, to see if the values have been set:

```
if(isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['post']))
{ ...
```

I'd also ensure that you are loading your [model](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html), are referring to it correctly.

---

In CodeIgniter, the [Input class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html) allows you to access `POST` data using this function:

```
$this->input->post('title');
```

as an alternative to this:

```
$_POST['title'];
```

There are some differences, which are explained in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
redirect('post/');
```

with

```
header('Location:your_url');
```

redirect will immidiately redirects you without knowing the previous statement has executed ot not but a header(); will do that

I think it is causing the problem

Comment: even i change that still not working may be somting problm on my controller

Comment: Are you wrote this in controller..??

Comment: Then what is the need of using MVC..??try to follow the structure plz,and after adding it to model let me know if any error then

Comment: actulay i am follow a codeigniter tutorial which is been doing just like this 

i want to build commenting system for use after they login do u know any step or on github such project so i couldl get hing

thanks

Answer (score 0):

change `if($_POST){` to this

`if($_POST['title'] && $_POST['post']){`